# Unable to find words when using freebase with word2vec

Tags: python-2.7, freebase, gensim, google-news

I am trying to use freebase along with gensim's word2vec to find similarity score between vectors of two word using following code.

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec()
model = models.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('freebase-vectors-skipgram1000-en.bin.gz', binary=True)
```

after creating a model based on freebase my code is giving me key error for any word.

```
model.similarity('microsoft', 'apple')
```

This is giving me `KeyError: 'microsoft'`

But when I use googlenews instead of freebase it works fine. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`model.similarity('/en/microsoft', '/en/apple')`

Answer (score 0):

That particular model has the Freebase /en IDs as the labels for the words.  There's another version which uses the MIDs (ie /m IDs).  You can find the English (or any other language) label associated with the word/entity using the Freebase API or data dump (you can't just slap "/en/" on the front of the word as you might guess from @scottyli's answer).

You might also want to look at this question & answer: [Using freebase vectors with gensim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480027/using-freebase-vectors-with-gensim)